# Override specific user avatar in buddypress

Tags: buddypress

Is there a way to override user avatar but not affecting other user. I already saw a code but it changes all defaults avatar. is it possible to do that in bp?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a scenario of when you'd want to 'override' an avatar.

As an admin, you can go into any profile and change the avatar - but then so can the user for that profile.

Comment: I want to do it by using the add filter function. I have a custom field for every user which contains the source of the avatar to be replaced in get_avatar. is it possible to have that and not affecting other user.

Comment: Then filter the avatar based on your custom field. It should work per user. Take at look at this re avatar filters: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49216/how-to-override-members-avatars-in-buddypress